# Как вытащить все выбранные checkbox через js и отправить их через formData

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

Необходимо примерно такие чекбоксы проверить на то, что они выбраны, выбранные положить в массив и затем отправить выбранный массив через formData js чтобы потом этот массив отправился по почте.

`<input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" name="district" value="Значение"> <input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" name="district" value="Значение"> <input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" name="district" value="Значение">`

Не знаю как это правильно сделать. Подскажите кто имел дело с таким.

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Answer (score 0):

```
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox__input:checked');
const formData = new FormData();

for(let checkBox of checkBoxes){
  formData.append(checkBox.name,true);
}
```